# grails mysql packet failed

Tags: java, mysql, grails-orm

I've been performing some database opreations select and insert for more than 12 hours using Grails and Gorm. I pool the connections too.
I suddenly get the following error and had to restart MySQL. Why?:

```
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:114)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:161)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:189)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2537)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2990)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2979)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3520)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1990)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2151)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2625)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2119)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2281)
    at grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder.invokeMethod(HibernateCriteriaBuilder.java:1167)
    at indiaweatherstation.PopulatedataService$_crawlAWS_closure2.doCall(PopulatedataService.groovy:89)
    at indiaweatherstation.PopulatedataService.crawlAWS(PopulatedataService.groovy:20)
    at indiaweatherstation.PopulatedataService$crawlAWS.call(Unknown Source)
    at indiaweatherstation.CrawlerController$_closure1.doCall(CrawlerController.groovy:16)
    at indiaweatherstation.CrawlerController$_closure1.doCall(CrawlerController.groovy)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the wait_timeout and interactive_timeout in mysql to a higher value